# Select every rows that contains all elements of group

Tags: sql, sql-server

Column [TYPE] has A or B or C. I want to select list of names those have all A,B,C in the table.

[image]

Result

[image]

```
    -- dealing with count
    select name from tempso group by name 
    having count(*) = (select count(distinct type) from tempso);
```

```
    -- dealing with specifying elements
    select name from tempso group by name 
    having type in all('A', 'B', 'C');
```

Actually, I wanted to do this with second method because that TYPES A,B,C have subtypes so risk of duplicates but I got this error below.

`Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10 syntax error 'all'...`

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: All you need to do is show us *what* you have tried.

Comment: I'd updated, Dale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having count(*) = (select count(distinct type) from t);
```

This assumes that the `name`/`type` rows are not repeated in the table.

Edit:

If you just want to check for A/B/C, then:

```
select name
from t
where type in ('A', 'B', 'C')
group by name
having count(*) = 3;
```

Or:

```
having count(distinct type) = 3
```

if the table has duplicates.

Comment: That query does not look like it would work. It checks if an integer count is equal to a set of strings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gordon. Accessing with count is almost best idea in current situation.

Comment: This still won't work, now that I think about it. For example, if one row is associated with `A`, `B`, and `D`, it will include it incorrectly.

Comment: @jpmc26 . . . No, because then `D` would be another type in the table, meaning the there are 4 of them.  And no `name`s would match.

Answer (score 0):

Your are used invalid function 'all'. and also it's not working in invalid in the HAVING clause.So, Please try this.

```
SELECT name,count(*)  AS cnt FROM tempso 
WHERE [type] in ('A', 'B', 'C')
GROUP BY name HAVING count(Name) >= 3
```

Comment: Thank you for comment Hemang, but I need the name that has all 'A', 'B', 'C' in original table.

Comment: Ok.Please replace just table name @tbl to tempso

Comment: Hemang sorry but I meant that I only wanted names those must have ALL 'A', 'B', 'C' in the table.

Comment: Please add having in the group by and I have updated the solution.

Comment: Thanks for spending your precious time with this article, Hemang.

Answer (score 0):

select Name from @table where Type IN ('A','B','C') group by Name having count(Name)>=3

Comment: 'Count' will be the best solution so far. Thank you Vikram.